# Is 2.2 is the latest version of magical record for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, magicalrecord

Can I know what is the latest version of magical record available for use? When I use pod to get it (pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand') I always get 2.2. IS there any new version available?

I see around 5 betas (2.3.0.beta-5) in github, but not sure whether I can use them or not.

Since I am at the end of project and about to release app to the store, I don't want to make any issues because of update.

Comment: why you risk to break your app for no good reason?

Comment: I have some core data migration issue which is not working, and I just to know if this is something to do magical record and an update can fix or something, one of my friend said he has latest and it working for him (migration), so I am just curious about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :tag => 'v2.3.0-beta.5'`

Here you go, if you wanna try the 2.3.0.beta-5 version. Don't forget to run `pod install` after modifying your Podfile ;)

Comment: How did you solve the migration issue...Im facing a similar one in iOS9 update